# Returning an Object with the function that created it as a method

Tags: javascript, function, object, recursion, methods

So i have created a function that searches deeply nested object and returns the object and the dot notation path to the result/results
i want to expand and add a method to the returned object so that you can then call the same search function again on the returned object however the function doesn't seem to return anything

the function itself is a recursive function and works as expected but the "getObject" method in the returned object always returns null even though i confirmed that the object is found when i call getObject separately

see below code

```
function outerFunction(){
    // Recursive function that passes result to ObjectToSearch 
    function getObject(objectToSearch, searchProp, searchValue) {
         ...                            
              results.push({
                           object:theObject,
                           path: dotNotationPath,
                           findObject: getObject
                                });
         ...
    return result;
   }
 return results   
}
```

https://codepen.io/JPDuffy/pen/wvdQVOr

Its probably something very simple but i am missing it
any help pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated

thank you

Comment: What is results? Where does it come from?

Comment: so results comes from the recursive getObjects which it searches all the key value pairs / array index's and if it finds a property match and then a search value match it adds the object as shown to the results array and once it has completed the search through all objects and arrays it returns the results ans an array of result objects

it all works fine other than adding findObject method which should just be another instance of getObject

Comment: I have added a few lines to help review

Comment: Where is `results` (or is it `result`) declared and initialised? Where is `getObject` actually called? Please provide a [mcve] we can run, preferably as a [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/1048572)

Comment: I have made a reproduction here, i have noticed however that the getObject method doesn't get added to the results in the code-pen example, open the console to see the results of the function
https://codepen.io/JPDuffy/pen/wvdQVOr

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve this one

what i ended up doing was to convert the "getObject" function into a class and then use the constructor of the class to call an internal method on initialization.

```
 class getObjResult {
    constructor(obj, searchProp, searchValue) {
      this.results = [];
      this.getObject(obj, searchProp, searchValue);
    }
```

then have it called

```
 this.results.push({
                object: theObject,
                path: [...pathArr].join("."),
                findObject: (obj, searchProp, searchValue) => {
                  return new getObjResult(obj, searchProp, searchValue);
                }
```

i have put the code pen update below

https://codepen.io/JPDuffy/pen/OJmrVYB